# css, button selection and html tags

Tags: asp.net, html, css, xml, xhtml

```
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/JScript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/fns.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.5.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('li').removeClass("first active first-active");
        $("a[href='DietPlan.aspx']").parent().addClass("first active first-active");
    });
```

Doesnt work still highlights the tab.

my script contained in js/JScript.js

```
    $(function () {
 $("a[href='<%=System.IO.Path.GetFileName(Request.PhysicalPath)%>']").parent().addClass("first active first-active");
});
```

...

```
                   <ul>
                        <li><a href="UserProfileWall.aspx">My Profile</a><span class="sep">&nbsp;</span></li>
                        <li><a href="DietPlan.aspx">My Diet Plan</a><span class="sep">&nbsp;</span></li>
                        <li><a href="WorkoutPlan.aspx">My Workout Plan</a><span class="sep">&nbsp;</span></li>
                    </ul>
```

css

```
    /*----- Start "Main definitions" -----*/
* { padding: 0; margin: 0; outline: 0; }

body {
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 1.2;
    font-family: Arial, "Trebuchet MS", sans-serif;
    color: #a0a0a0;
    background: url(images/bg.gif) repeat 0 0;
    text-align: left;
}

a img { border: 0; }
a { color: #a0a0a0; text-decoration: underline; }
a:hover { text-decoration: none; }

.left { float: left; display: inline; }
.right { float: right; display: inline; }

.cl, .clear { display: block; height: 0; font-size: 0; line-height: 0; text-indent: -4000px; clear: both; }
.field { font-size: 12px; color: #484848; font-family: Arial, "Trebuchet MS", sans-serif; color: #000; border: solid 1px #a0a0a0; width: 140px; padding: 2px 5px; }

/*----- End "Main definitions" -----*/

.shell { width: 914px; margin: 0 auto; }

#page { padding-bottom: 30px; }

#header { width: 100%; position: relative; margin-bottom: 5px; }

#logo { text-transform: uppercase; line-height: 1; padding-bottom: 15px; }
#logo h1 { font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: bold; font-size: 30px; color: #fff; }
#logo h1 a { color: #fff; text-decoration: none; }
#logo h1 a span { color: #7ab7e2; }
#logo .description { font-size: 10px; color: #cfd2d9; }

#top-nav { float: right; display: inline; margin-bottom: 2px; }
#top-nav ul { float: left; display: inline; font-size: 10px; line-height: 31px; color: #fff; text-transform: uppercase; background: url(images/top-nav-bg.jpg) repeat-x 0 0; }
#top-nav ul li { float: left; display: inline; list-style-type: none; }
#top-nav ul li a { float: left; display: inline; color: #fff; text-decoration: none; padding: 0 10px 0 8px; background: url(images/top-nav-sep.gif) no-repeat right 0; }
#top-nav ul li a:hover { text-decoration: underline; }
#top-nav ul li.last { padding-right: 4px; background: url(images/top-nav-last.gif) no-repeat right 0; }
#top-nav ul li.last a { background: none; }
#top-nav ul li.home { width: 88px; background: url(images/top-nav-home.gif) no-repeat 0 0; }
#top-nav ul li.home a { background: none; width: 67px; height: 31px; line-height: 29px; padding: 0; color: #141414; font-weight: bold; padding-left: 21px; }

#main-nav { float: right; display: inline; line-height: 32px; background: url(images/main-nav-bg.gif) repeat-x 0 0; }
#main-nav .bg-right { background: url(images/main-nav-bg-right.gif) no-repeat right 0; }
#main-nav .bg-left { background: url(images/main-nav-bg-left.gif) no-repeat 0 0; padding-left: 32px; width: 676px; }
#main-nav ul { height: 32px; font-size: 10px; color: #a8a8a8; text-transform: uppercase; }
#main-nav ul li { float: left; display: inline; list-style-type: none; background: url(images/main-nav-sep.gif) no-repeat right 0; }
#main-nav ul li a { float: left; display: inline; text-decoration: none; color: #a8a8a8; padding: 0 11px 0 9px; }
#main-nav ul li a:hover { text-decoration: underline; }

#sort-nav { line-height: 46px; background: url(images/sort-nav-bg.gif) repeat-x 0 0; }
#sort-nav .bg-left { background: url(images/sort-nav-bg-left.gif) no-repeat 0 0; position: relative; height: 46px; }
#sort-nav .bg-right { background: url(images/sort-nav-bg-right.gif) no-repeat right 0; position: relative; height: 46px; }
#sort-nav ul li { float: left; display: inline; list-style-type: none; height: 46px; }
#sort-nav ul li a { float: left; display: inline; font-size: 13px; font-weight: bold; color: #282828; text-decoration: none; padding: 0 19px; }
#sort-nav ul li span.sep { float: left; display: inline; width: 2px; height: 46px; font-size: 0; line-height: 0; text-indent: -4000px; background: url(images/sort-nav-sep.gif); }
#sort-nav ul li a:hover { text-decoration: underline; }
#sort-nav ul li.active a { color: #fff; text-decoration: none; }
#sort-nav ul li.active a:hover { text-decoration: none; }
#sort-nav ul li.first-active a { background: url(images/nav-active-first.gif) no-repeat 0 0; }
#sort-nav ul li.active span.sep { background-image: url(images/nav-active-sep.gif); }
#sort-nav ul li.active { background: url(images/nav-active-bg.gif) repeat-x 0 0; }



#main { background: #050505 url(images/main-bg.gif) no-repeat 0 0; padding-top: 10px; }
#main-bot { background: url(images/main-bot-bg.gif) no-repeat 0 bottom; padding: 0 10px 2px 10px; height: 100%; position: relative; }
#sidebar { float: left; display: inline; width: 226px; }
#content { float: right; display: inline; width: 660px; }

.block { margin-bottom: 10px; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: 0 0; }
.block .block-bot { height: 100%; position: relative; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: 0 bottom; }
.block .block-cnt { padding: 10px 10px 10px 9px; }

.block .head { background: url(images/block-head.gif) no-repeat 0 0; padding-left: 15px; }
.block .head .head-cnt { background: url(images/block-head.gif) no-repeat right 0; line-height: 38px; height: 38px; padding-right: 13px; }
.block .head h3 { font-size: 15px; font-weight: bold; color: #262727; }
.block .head .view-all { float: right; display: inline; width: 61px; height: 18px; line-height: 16px; background: url(images/block-head-view-all.gif); margin-top: 12px; }
.block .head .view-all { color: #656565; font-size: 10px; text-decoration: none; text-align: center; }
.block .head .view-all:hover { text-decoration: underline; }

#content .block { background-image: url(images/content-block-top.gif); background-color: #313131; width: 657px; }
#content .block .block-bot { background-image: url(images/content-block-bot.gif); }

#sidebar .block { background-image: url(images/sidebar-block-top.gif); background-color: #484848; width: 226px; }
#sidebar .block .block-bot { background-image: url(images/sidebar-block-bot.gif); }


#search .block-cnt { padding: 5px 5px 5px 4px; }
#search .fieldplace { float: left; display: inline; width: 170px; height: 22px; background: url(images/search-field.gif) no-repeat 0 0; padding-left: 18px; }
#search .fieldplace .field { padding: 3px 6px 4px; width: 158px; border: none; background: none; }
#search .button { float: left; display: inline; width: 29px; height: 22px; font-size: 0; line-height: 0; text-indent: -4000px; cursor: pointer; border: 0; }
#search .button { background: url(images/search-button.gif) no-repeat 0 0; }

#sign .block-cnt { padding: 6px 5px 5px 5px; }
#sign .button { display: block; font-size: 11px; font-weight: bold; text-align: center; color: #fff; text-decoration: none; text-transform: uppercase; line-height: 29px; }
#sign .button { width: 105px; height: 29px; background: url(images/sign-button.gif) no-repeat 0 0; }
#sign .button:hover { background-position: 0 bottom; }
#sign .button-left { float: left; display: inline; }
#sign .button-right { float: right; display: inline; }
#sign .center { text-align: center; font-size: 11px; line-height: 16px; margin-top: 4px; }
#sign .center a { color: #35cfd9; }

#sidebar .articles .article { padding: 8px 7px; background: url(images/sidebar-article-sep.gif) repeat-x 0 bottom; font-size: 11px; color: #a0a0a0; }
#sidebar .articles h4 { color: #fff; font-weight: bold; font-size: 12px; }
#sidebar .articles h4 a { color: #fff; text-decoration: none; }
#sidebar .articles h4 a:hover { color: #ccc; }
#sidebar .articles .view-all { font-size: 10px; letter-spacing: 0.5px; line-height: 24px; float: right; display: inline; margin-right: 6px; }

#sidebar .image-articles .image { float: left; display: inline; width: 55px; }
#sidebar .image-articles .image img { padding: 1px; border: solid 1px #1e1e1e; width: 208px; 
height: 148px; }
#sidebar .image-articles .cnt { float: right; display: inline; width: 150px; }

#sidebar .text-articles .article { padding: 8px 10px; font-size: 12px; }
#sidebar .text-articles h4 { font-size: 13px; }

#content .articles h4 { font-size: 19px; font-weight: bold; color: #ccc; margin: 4px 0 2px; }
#content .articles h4 a { text-decoration: none; color: #ccc; }
#content .articles h4 a:hover { color: #fff; }

#content .col-articles .image img { padding: 1px; border: solid 1px #050505; width: 194px; height: 194px; }
#content .col-articles .article { float: left; display: inline; margin: 17px 0 10px 15px; width: 198px; }

#content .row-articles .article { padding: 10px 15px 12px 15px; background: url(images/content-article-sep.gif) repeat-x 0 bottom; }
#content .row-articles .last-article { background: none; }
#content .row-articles .image { float: left; display: inline; width: 194px; }
#content .row-articles .image img { width: 194px; }
#content .row-articles .cnt { float: right; display: inline; width: 420px; }
#content .row-articles h4 { margin-top: 0; line-height: 20px; }
#content .row-articles h4 a { color: #e4e4e4; }

#slider { width: 638px; height: 357px; position: relative; }
#slider .buttons { position: absolute; top: 250px; right: 15px; z-index: 101; }
#slider .buttons span { float: left; display: inline; width: 28px; height: 27px; font-size: 0; line-height: 0; text-indent: -4000px; cursor: pointer; margin-left: 2px; }
#slider .buttons span.prev { background: url(images/button-prev.png) no-repeat 0 0; }
#slider .buttons span.next { background: url(images/button-next.png) no-repeat 0 0; }
#slider .holder { width: 638px; height: 357px; position: relative; overflow: hidden; }
#slider .content { height: 357px; width: 100000px; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; }
#slider .fragment { float: left; display: inline; width: 638px; height: 357px; list-style-type: none; }
#slider .fragment .image { position: relative; width: 638px; height: 287px; }
#slider .frame { width: 638px; height: 287px; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; z-index: 100; background: url(images/slider-image-bg.png) no-repeat 0 0; }
#slider .frame { font-size: 0; line-height: 0; text-indent: -4000px; }
#slider .fragment .cnt { margin-top: 5px; height: 49px; background: url(images/slider-cnt-bg.gif) repeat-x; color: #fff; font-size: 11px; line-height: 1.4; padding: 8px 15px; }
#slider .fragment .cnt .side-a { float: left; display: inline; width: 150px; }
#slider .fragment .cnt .side-b { float: right; display: inline; width: 430px; }
#slider .fragment .cnt h4 { font-size: 19px; font-weight: bold; color: #212121; text-transform: uppercase; margin-bottom: 5px; }
#slider .fragment .cnt .rating li { float: left; display: inline; list-style-type: none; font-size: 9px; color: #050505; text-transform: uppercase; margin-right: 1px; }
#slider .fragment .cnt .rating li .star { float: left; display: inline; width: 15px; height: 15px; font-size: 0; line-height: 0; text-indent: -4000px; }
#slider .fragment .cnt .rating li .empty-star { background: url(images/empty-star.gif); }
#slider .fragment .cnt .rating li .full-star { background: url(images/full-star.gif); }
#slider .fragment .cnt .rating li .votes { float: left; display: inline; margin-top: 3px; margin-left: 4px; }

#footer .copy { font-size: 10px; color: #363636; text-transform: uppercase; text-align: right; padding: 20px 0; }
#footer .copy a{ color: #363636; }
#footer .navs { background: #222 url(images/footer-navs-top.gif) no-repeat 0 0; text-align: center; font-size: 10px; text-transform: uppercase; color: #656565; height: 100%; position: relative; }
#footer .navs .navs-bot { background: url(images/footer-navs-bot.gif) no-repeat 0 bottom; height: 100%; position: relative; }
#footer .navs ul { margin: 10px 0; }
#footer .navs ul li { list-style-type: none; display: inline; padding: 0 6px; }
#footer .navs ul li a { color: #656565; text-decoration: none; }
#footer .navs ul li a:hover { text-decoration: underline; }
```

Comment: are you placing the "active" class via javascript? or with the server-side scripting?

Comment: so even with `<li class="active"><a href="WorkoutPlan.aspx">My Workout Plan</a><span class="sep">&nbsp;</span></li>` it doesn't highlight? Have you tried hard-coded just to be sure?

Comment: hard coding does make it active

Comment: but obviously I dont want them all highlighted at the same time only when your on the active page

Comment: that means your javascript is faulty, check the answer below for a way to add/remove classes. BTW, maybe it would be better to set the class via the asp instead of using javascript, or is it calling the menu items via AJAX?

Comment: Can you post the javascript code you're using to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your link clicks reload the current page your "My Profile" tag will be always selected.

One option would be to select the current tab via server side script, this can be done many ways however here is one.
If the menu is on a master page, you will need to define some way to find out which page you are on server side.

```
<ul>
    <li <%=CurrentPage == "Profile" ? "class=\"first active first-active\"" : "" %>>
      <a href="UserProfileWall.aspx">My Profile</a>
      <span class="sep">&nbsp;</span>
    </li>
    <li <%=CurrentPage == "DietPlan" ? "class=\"first active first-active\"" : "" %>>
      <a href="DietPlan.aspx">My Diet Plan </a>
      <span class="sep">&nbsp;</span></li>
    <li <%=CurrentPage == "WorkOutPlan" ? "class=\"first active first-active\"" : "" %>>
      <a href="WorkoutPlan.aspx">My Workout Plan</a>
      <span class="sep">&nbsp;</span></li>
</ul>
```

This is all pseudo code, but the idea is you only want to set `class="first active first-active"` when you are on the current page via some sort of server side conditional.

If the menu is on each page, `UserProfileWall.aspx`, `DietPlan.aspx` it is a bit easier...
`UserProfileWall.aspx` would be like this:

```
<ul>
    <li class="first active first-active"><a href="UserProfileWall.aspx">My Profile</a><span class="sep">&nbsp;</span></li>
    <li><a href="DietPlan.aspx">My Diet Plan </a><span class="sep">&nbsp;</span></li>
    <li><a href="WorkoutPlan.aspx">My Workout Plan</a><span class="sep">&nbsp;</span></li>
    <li><a href="#">Research</a><span class="sep">&nbsp;</span></li>
    <li><a href="#">Research</a><span class="sep">&nbsp;</span></li>
</ul>
```

`DietPlan.aspx` would be like this...

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="UserProfileWall.aspx">My Profile</a><span class="sep">&nbsp;</span></li>
    <li class="first active first-active"><a href="DietPlan.aspx">My Diet Plan </a><span class="sep">&nbsp;</span></li>
    <li><a href="WorkoutPlan.aspx">My Workout Plan</a><span class="sep">&nbsp;</span></li>
    <li><a href="#">Research</a><span class="sep">&nbsp;</span></li>
    <li><a href="#">Research</a><span class="sep">&nbsp;</span></li>
</ul>
```

And so on for the rest of your pages..

Now this is just one way you could also break this out to a user control that has a property as the current page for example.

This could be done via javascript as well (untested).

```
$(function(){
     $("a[href='<%=System.IO.Path.GetFileName(Request.PhysicalPath)%>']").parent().addClass("first active first-active");
});
```

Which should generate something like this:

```
$(function(){
  $("a[href='DietPlan.aspx']").parent().addClass("first active first-active");
});
```

**Update**

Having server script blocks in your *.js files will not be processed by .net (by default), try changing the following:
Change:

```
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/JScript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/fns.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.5.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('li').removeClass("first active first-active");
        $("a[href='DietPlan.aspx']").parent().addClass("first active first-active");
    });
```

To:

```
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/JScript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/fns.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.5.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
  $("a[href='<%=System.IO.Path.GetFileName(Request.PhysicalPath)%>']").parent().addClass("first active first-active");
});
```

Comment: it is on a master page, everything else is held in content place holders, but the first part u gave me has errors? Contentpage does not exist should i change that to UserProfile.master? also u repeated the workout plan for all after the content page? :S

Comment: Fixed the typo, CurrentPage was just a place holder for some logic. On the MyProfile page you could do something like this `ViewState["CurrentPage"] = "Profile"` and then in the link you could do  `ViewState["CurrentPage"] == "Profile"` or use the PhysicalPath like `System.IO.Path.GetFileName(Request.PhysicalPath) == "UserProfileWall.aspx"`

Comment: My only other suggestion is to edit your question and outline each piece.  The master page layout, the page that references the master page, and any other pieces that are used to build your final layout.

Comment: Valid `<script>` tags need to be like this `<script type="text/javascript"></script>`  Also see my update to wrap the selector in a document ready to be like the example.

Comment: If you go the javascript route, remove all class values from the li, and let the javascript add the class for you which should happen on each page load as each page should produce a different selector via the `GetFileName(Request.PhysicalPath)`

Comment: i tryed '$('li').parent().removeClass("first active first-active");'

Comment: `$('li').parent().removeClass("first active first-active");` will point towards your `<ul/>` if you want to use jQuery to remove the class you need to point to your `<li/>` $('li').removeClass("first active first-active");.  If this doesnt help, *please* edit your answer I am getting lost on what is going on now.

Comment: You can't have server script in a .js file, take that piece from your JScript.js file and place that in your aspx page.  This will force the server to evaluate the script block and should place the correct aspx page, see update...

Answer (score 2):

Define a selected class in your css.
ex:

```
.selected{
background:red;
}
```

Using jQuery you can do this.

```
$('li').click(function() {
    $('li').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
});
```

Now only the clicked `li` link will have the class="selected" and therefore the background red.

### Check working example at http://jsfiddle.net/MRVpD/

Comment: yeah thanks for that but I already know this, and background = red is abit simplistic compared to what im trying to achieve my background for the tab calls an image (refer to css i posted) maybe im placing my jquery in the wrong place or my jquery is messed up, unfortunately its far to big to post here??

Comment: @garrith You can do what ever you want with the selected class. Your are not limited to just background color. if you want to do background image instead then you can do `background:transparent url(image.jpg) no-repeat 0 0;` The point is that is how you keep one link highlighted with the selected class. if you have another questions relating to why you jQuery is not working then start another question.

Comment: @garrith use this to load jQuery. place it just before your closing `</body>` tag. `<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.5.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>` then place the jQuery code i have in my answer just below that and before the `</body>`

Comment: @garrith This is how your layout should be like http://jsfiddle.net/86z5g/. If you have any javaScript issues or conflicts, post another question relating to the issue.

Comment: @garrith The best way to do it is give your UL an id ex: `id="mymenu`, then with jQuery you can do  `$('li', '#mymenu')` to reference the ul's inside it. That way we only target the li's whithin `#mymenu` and not any other li's.

Comment: I gave you a working solution for your question and provided you with a live example. How you implemented is up to you. Also What do you mean exactly when you say id not supported. Why can't you add an id to a ul. That's the easiest way to have reference to it.