# jquery problem on tab selection

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html

I have a problem related to my previous article [css, button selection and html tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5211879/css-button-selection-and-html-tags)

Not very good with javascript if any one could offer some insight as to where im going.

Thanks to any one who can help

```
$(function() {

$('input.field').
focus(function() {
    if(this.title==this.value) {
        this.value = '';
    }
}).
blur(function(){
    if(this.value=='') {
        this.value = this.title;
    }
});

var currentPage = 1;
$('#slider .buttons span').live('click', function() {
    var timeout = setTimeout(function() {$("img").trigger("slidermove")}, 300);
    var fragments_count = $(this).parents('#slider:eq(0)').find('.fragment').length;
    var fragmet_width = $(this).parents('#slider:eq(0)').find('.fragment').width();
    var perPage = 1;
    var numPages = Math.ceil(fragments_count/perPage);
    var stepMove = fragmet_width*perPage;
    var container = $(this).parents('#slider:eq(0)').find('.content');
    var firstPosition = 0;
    var lastPosition = -((numPages-1)*stepMove);

    if ($(this).hasClass('next')) {
        currentPage ++;
        if (currentPage > numPages) {
            currentPage = 1;
            container.animate({'left': firstPosition});
            return;
        };
        container.animate({'left': -((currentPage - 1)*stepMove)});
    };
    if ($(this).hasClass('prev')) {
        currentPage --;
        if (currentPage < 1) {
            currentPage = numPages;
            container.animate({'left': lastPosition});
            return;
        };
        container.animate({'left': -((currentPage-1)*stepMove)});
    };
});});
```

[image]

Comment: It would be a lot easier to help you if you only posted your own javascript. The jQuery source is not necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jQuery code you have in your description is the minimized version. If you download jQuery from their site, you'll see there is the .min.js file and the standard .js file. The fist takes up less space, the second is the readable source. You have the first.

Comment: right im lost as I only dragged n dropped these files into asp.net they work fine I have the js and min.js files but the first js is the slider function for a different part of the site. How do I convert the min.js back into a readable format and wont it be huge in comparison? If its designed to shrink the file? As the min.js I have atm is 50+K in characters.

Comment: I see! Your best bet is to get jQuery from the site (jquery.com) and use the non-minified .js file. I hope it's the same version as your minified jQuery file.

Comment: erm on the site but when i click download it takes me to a page with the above mentioned code? :S kind of lost here maybe my single js file that I have is missing the code for my previous post on my ui tabs eeeeeeeeeeeeekkkkkk

Comment: Make sure to check 'development' just above the download link.

Answer (score 1):

The JavaScript is [minified](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minification_%28programming%29).

> Components and libraries for Web
>   applications and websites have been
>   developed to optimize file requests
>   and quicken page load times by
>   reducing the size of various files.
>   JavaScript and CSS resources may be
>   minified, preserving their behavior
>   while considerably reducing their file
>   size. Libraries such as JavaScript
>   Optimizer, pack:tag, Minify,
>   Lightweight, CssMin,
>   jsmin-php, MiniME, and
>   ShrinkSafe are capable of such
>   on-the-fly optimizations.

During development you could use the normal [jQuery](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.1.js).

From the jQuery page, min is 29k while the normal is 212k.

If you wish to minify your own javascript for production deployment some resources are:

1. [Jsmin](http://www.crockford.com/javascript/jsmin.html)
2. [Microsoft Jax Minifier](http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/ajaxminquickstart.ashx)
3. [Online YUI compressor](http://www.refresh-sf.com/yui/)

Comment: im still lost as to my first post question these are templates im playing with, And I cant find the function for active ui for my tabs on my first post about this. I know that my slider function wont work with the min.js and or the .js both posted above, ive tryed removing them one or other so they are linked but within the .js is only the slider function (image rotator) but the tabs on the actual page dont change there background?

Comment: I am a bit confused, this question you are trying to get the image rotator to work? In regards to your other question, when you click on the page the tab doesn't remain `selected`?

Comment: no the image rotator works fine, its my tabs at the top of my page that arent working well it does work for the first <li> but when i click on a new tab to go else where on the page the highlighted profile is still highlighted and the page and tab ive clicked on isnt highlighted.

Comment: added what I have as you can see from the image my profile is highlight yet its not java doing it but when i click on my diet plan or workout they dont become the same as my profile. my css and html code is on the link above

Comment: I think I know what is going on, I will post on your other question.

Comment: hey did u post yet? Not being pushy just getting lost in my own posts cheers bud